# DateTime format for 9/14/2016 19:31

Tags: datetime, .net-core, f#, datetime-format

I am doing an F# course by Richard Broida. In one lecture I am supposed to parse a CSV document. Everything works fine except for parsing datetime. My local culture settings are Slovak (sk-SK) and I am trying to parse the following datetime string:

`9/14/2016 19:31`

I have read through the CSV file and found out that months, days and hours can all have both one or two digits. Years always have **4** digits and minutes always have **2** digits. So, the datetime `10/7/2016 9:01` is also a valid one.

I have created an adapter function:

```
let dateTimeParseAdapter format provider date = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, provider)
```

and then called

```
dateTimeParseAdapter "M/d/yyyy h:mm" CultureInfo.InvariantCulture "9/14/2016 19:31"
```

but I got an exception message saying

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I tried adjusting the format string to exactly match the number of digits in my single date. However, even the following code resulted in the same error message.

```
dateTimeParseAdapter "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm" CultureInfo.InvariantCulture "9/14/2016 19:31"
```

Why am I getting the exception message? Should I change the `CultureInfo` settings? Or is there a pre-defined datetime format to parse my datetimes?

Comment: `H:mm` isntead of `h:mm`

Comment: why c# tsg? if its F#

Comment: @BugFinder it's dotnet at all

Comment: @FoggyFinder Well.. it could be applied but the code is F#, and so is the text, theres no need for c# tags

Comment: @BugFinder another option - C# tag is more popular

Comment: @FoggyFinder You are making up excuses for a question thats not yours!

Comment: @BugFinder I'm just trying to shed light on reasons ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @BugFinder It is exactly as FoggyFinder writes - the issue applies also for C# and C# tag is more popular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When working with **24** hour format you should use `H` (`HH`) not `h` `hh` (which is for **12** hour format) pattern:

```
 format = @"M/d/yyyy H:mm";
```

Answer (score 3):

since you are using 24 hour in your value you must put capitals in hours. Change

```
 "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
```

to

```
 "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
```